# Why does the inner dimension need to be the same for matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrix-multiplication

If we have two matrices, why does the inner dimension need to be the same if we want to do matrix multiplication?

I understand that some of the dot products might have NaNs but, we could just ignore those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply the way matrix multiplication is defined:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Matrix_multiplication_diagram_2.svg/313px-Matrix_multiplication_diagram_2.svg.png]

The red cell is `a_1_1 * b_1_2 + a_1_2 * b_2_2`. How would you calculate with `a_1_1`, `a_1_2`, `b_1_2`, `b_2_2` and `b_3_2`?

The dot product isn't defined for different vector lengths either. Some programs might decide to accept the dot product of a 2-D vector and a 3-D vector by setting the Z value of the 2-D vector to `0`.

Comment: Thanks. I know this was a weird question. But I like seeing the responses to simple questions.

Comment: Can't we redefine the dot product? Like call it the "super dot product"? That supports this operation?

Comment: @echo I'm afraid your super dot product looks like [this](http://c8.alamy.com/comp/CFG060/forcing-a-square-peg-into-a-round-hole-with-the-help-of-a-hammer-CFG060.jpg).

Comment: LOL. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using a math package or anything, but if you are looking at matrix multiplication from a pure math standpoint, the fact that sometimes NaN is a possibility means that the mathematical definition has to account for this. The package that you are using is just defining the mathematical operation in code.

Dot products are relatively simple though, and if the way that it is defined in whatever you are using isn't exactly what you need, then it would be a relatively easy task to define your own function that does the dot product.